# vscode problemMatcher doesn't not recognize Tasking compiler warnings

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-problem-matcher

The following Tasks.json
Problem matcher regular expression should match the following typical warning. But it doesn't.
ctc W505: ["somedirectory/somefile.c" 350/18] implicit declaration blah blah blah

What is the issue ? I verified the built-in parser matches gcc output errors and warnings.

Thanks,

Satish K

```
"tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build.bat",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "build.bat",
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpptools",
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${env:PWD}"
                ],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^ctc W(\\d+): \\[\\\"(.*)\\\" (\\d+)\\\/(\\d+)\\] (.*)$",
                    "file": 2,
                    "line": 3,
                    "column": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in regex101.com (ECMAScript(JavaScript)):

```
^ctc\s+(W|E)(\d+): \["(.*)" (\d+)\/(\d+)\] (.*)
```

And this in VS Code:

```
"problemMatcher": {
            "owner": "TASKING",
            "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceFolder}"],
            "pattern": {
                "regexp": "^ctc\\s+(W|E)(\\d+): \\[\"(.*)\" (\\d+)\/(\\d+)\\] (.*)",
                "severity": 1,
                "code": 2,
                "file": 3,
                "line": 4,
                "column": 5,
                "message": 6
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You add an additional `\` to the expression, you only need to escape the `"` and you don't need to escape `/`

```
"tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build.bat",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "build.bat",
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpptools",
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${env:PWD}"
                ],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^ctc W(\\d+): \\[\"(.*)\" (\\d+)/(\\d+)\\] (.*)$",
                    "file": 2,
                    "line": 3,
                    "column": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
```

---

**Edit**

This works in regex101 (flavor Javascript)

```
^ctc W(\d+): \["(.*)" (\d+)\/(\d+)\] (.*)$
```

To translate it to a JSON string, escape `\"` and regex also wants you to escape `/` but that would only be needed if you use the regex in a literal Javascript (like `/\d+/g`) but we don't do that in VSC, but it won't hurt.

Resulting in:

```
"^ctc W(\\d+): \\[\"(.*)\" (\\d+)\\/(\\d+)\\] (.*)$"
```

Comment: That didn't work either. Also verified it in regex101.com

Comment: @satish I tried in regex101 and it complained about the non escaped `/`

Comment: To test without ctc, i just echoed the following in build.bat
  @echo ctc W505: ["somedirectory/somefile.c" 350/18] implicit declaration blah blah 
Vscode recognizes file path by default. But it cannot get the line and column number.

Comment: @satish I tested it with the updated regex and it works, line and column are fetched

Comment: It works with regex. But vscode could not identify line and column numbers. To reproduce the issue, you can execute build.bat with the echo statement inside it.

Comment: @satish I did, and the problem tab shows me the line and column numbers in [] and when I click on that line it jumps to the file and line  number and has a red squiggle at the location.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get this to work. But I ran the working regex101 through a json escpare. It did some more escaping of slashes and ended up as:

```
"regexp": "^ctc W(\\d+): \\[\\\"(.*)\\\" (\\d+)\\/(\\d+)\\] (.*)$",
```